# Lilypond: forcing a line break within lyrics

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to replicate something I've seen in other settings of choral Preces and Responses. In the [Ayleward Responses](http://www2.cpdl.org/wiki/images/4/43/Ayleward_Preces_and_Responses.pdf), page 4, the words "which art... ...from evil" are split over two lines.

How would you go about doing this in lilypond? In my code I have all four voices with their lyrics from a single \lyricmode entry (i.e. a "verse" Lyric).

Comment: Please add a minimal example to your question. This is certainly possible in LilyPond, but the solution depends on the input you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a second \lyricmode entry to create a new stanza. I don't think there are other ways. That's why I asked for a minimal example.. to know also what you tried so far. Anyway, here's a version which works:

```
\version "2.19.82"

\paper {
  ragged-right = ##f
}

global = {
  \key d \major
  \time 4/4
}

% 1st stanza
StanzaOne = \lyricmode {
  which_art2 in_heaven…
  A -- men.
}

% 2nd stanza
StanzaTwo = \lyricmode {
  …but_deliver_us from_evil.
  A -- men
}

\new StaffGroup <<
  <<
    \new Staff { \global \clef treble a'1 | a'2 a' }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaOne }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaTwo }
  >>
  <<
    \new Staff { \global \clef treble a'1 | fis'2 e' }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaOne }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaTwo }
  >>
  <<
    \new Staff { \global \clef treble a'1 | d''2 cis'' }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaOne }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaTwo }
  >>
  <<
    \new Staff { \global \clef bass a1 | d2 a, }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaOne }
    \new Lyrics { \StanzaTwo }
  >>
>>
```

[image: two stanza lyrics example]